# Parameterization of Rmarkdown Files

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown

I'm trying to loop through a list of employee IDs to create a report for each id.

I know I have to declare the parameter in the YAML but I'm getting a scanner error.

```
---
title: "Employee Record"
params:
  MASTER_ID: !r uniqueID
output: pdf_document
---
**Employee ID:** `r params$MASTER_ID`
```

The field of employee ids in the dataset is called MASTER_ID and uniqueID is just a list of each unique employee id (length = 880)

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error in yaml::yaml.load(string, ...) : 
  Scanner error: while scanning a simple key at line 3, column 1 could not find expected ':' at line 4, column 1
```

I don't have any extra white spaces or anything so i'm not sure what I'm missing

Comment: `!r` commands in the header are run before anything else is executed. Since `uniqueID` isn't a built-in R object, it will cause an error. You should put a default value in your YAML header, and then pass in specific values via `render()` as [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/params-knit.html).

Comment: So I just changed the code to do that where the default value is 1 and in the render command i use `render('Report.Rmd',params = list(MASTER_ID=unique(Salary$MASTER_ID)))` still getting the YAML error

Comment: You should be passing a single value at a time not vector of values.

Comment: Okay and if I wanted to process a vector of values I'd use a for loop for each value of the vector?

Comment: Yes. That is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up on what others have already said, it is best to call your Rmd from a separate R file using the `rmarkdown::render` function. This also allows you to easily control the file naming and output location.

```
employees <- 1:10

for (i in employees) {
  rmarkdown::render("test_pdf.Rmd",
                    params = list(MASTER_ID = i),
                    output_file = paste0('employee-', i, ".pdf"),
                    output_dir = '/reports')
}
```

With `test_pdf.Rmd` containing:

```
title: "Employee Record"
params:
  MASTER_ID: 
    value: 1
output: pdf_document
---
**Employee ID:** `r params$MASTER_ID`
```